# How can I intercept the REST API's requests in my browser using ngrok?

Tags: docker, rest, reverse-proxy, ngrok

I am trying to intercept the REST request which comes to my Firefox browser using the following steps but sadly it doesn't work. Here are the steps to reproduce the problem:

- Open any website in your browser which sends some REST requests (such as https://www.bbc.com/)
- Make sure you have a valid authentication token from ngrok.
- Create a `ngrok.yml` file to configure the ngrok tunnels:

  ```yaml
   authtoken: YOUR_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN

    tunnels:
      app4200:
        addr: 4200
        proto: http
        bind_tls: true

      app443:
        addr: 443
        proto: http
        bind_tls: true
  ```

Finally run ngrok using Docker in the same directory that you have `ngrok.yml`:

```
docker run -it -v ./ngrok.yml:/ngrok/ngrok.yml -e NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=YOUR_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN ngrok/ngrok:latest http host.docker.internal:4200
```

**Note**: in my real case, I need to also monitor port 4200 on my localhost because I have an Angular app running on this port, and that's the main reason to use the `ngrok.yml` file .

I can successfully intercept requests on port 4200, however my main question here is about port 443 where the HTTPS REST requests go. As you can see in the below image, although there are a lot of GET requests on my browser, nothing is logged in the ngrok console.

[image]

I also noticed that there is only one connection created, although I had requested two Tunnels in my YAML file.

Comment: Your question is confusing. It talks about reverse proxying your own app, but then you go on to talk about (normal) proxying bbc.com. You also talk about REST requests coming to Firefox. REST requests don't come to the browser. They come *from* the browser. And fwiw, I didn't down vote.

Comment: @HansKilian, the reason that i use reverse proxy to collect the requests, is that i have an Angular app in docker container which sends some GET requests. And i would like to capture them. Just to simplify the question, i made the assumption that i just want to capture the requests on browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To intercept the REST API's requests in your browser using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), you would need to make sure your local web traffic is routed through ngrok's tunnel.

But ngrok is primarily designed to expose local servers to the internet, and by itself, it does not intercept traffic that is not directed to it.
So you need to set up a local proxy server that can intercept HTTPS requests. That proxy will act as a man-in-the-middle and allow you to inspect the traffic.

Your browser has to be configured to use this local proxy for its internet connection. That way, all requests from your browser will go through the proxy.
Configure ngrok to expose your local proxy server to the internet. That step is what you have already done, but instead of directing ngrok to your app on port 4200, you will direct it to the local proxy's port.

Since HTTPS is encrypted, your local proxy needs to be able to decrypt HTTPS traffic. Tools like [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) can do this (`pipx install mitmproxy` + `mitmproxy --port 8081` if 8080 is already taken), but you will need to install the proxy's certificate as a trusted certificate in your browser to avoid security warnings: see "[About Certificates](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/)".

```
Browser ──> Local Proxy (decrypts HTTPS) ──> ngrok ──> Internet
```

Your `ngrok.yml` file should create a tunnel for the mitmproxy port instead of port 443:

```yaml
authtoken: YOUR_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN

tunnels:
  app4200:
    addr: 4200
    proto: http
    bind_tls: true

  mitmproxy:
    addr: 8081 # The port mitmproxy is running on
    proto: http
    bind_tls: true
```

And `docker run -it -v $(pwd)/ngrok.yml:/ngrok/ngrok.yml -e NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=YOUR_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN ngrok/ngrok:latest start --all`.
Go to your browser settings and configure it to use the proxy server. You will typically enter 127.0.0.1 as the proxy address and 8081 (or whatever port you chose) as the port.

Regarding ngrok not logging the HTTPS requests, ngrok will only log the traffic that is directed to its tunnel. If you are trying to intercept traffic that goes to `https://www.bbc.com/`, that traffic is not going through ngrok by default. To intercept this, you would need your browser to send its requests to ngrok (by using a local proxy, as mentioned).

You mentioned that you need to monitor both port 4200 and port 443. Port 4200 is for your Angular app, which is fine, but for HTTPS requests, monitoring port 443 directly will not work because ngrok cannot intercept encrypted traffic not meant for it. You would need the local proxy to handle the HTTPS connections.

If you correctly set up a proxy and direct your browser to use it, ngrok should show all the requests passing through, provided that the proxy is set up to route its traffic through ngrok.

For the single connection issue, this could be due to the configuration not being picked up correctly or ngrok not being able to bind to the specified ports due to permissions or other services using those ports. Review the logs for any errors and confirm that both ngrok and your local proxy are correctly set up and have the necessary permissions to bind to the required ports.